# Can the output of find with the -printf flag be colorized?

Tags: find, printf

The command

```
find . -type l -not -xtype l -printf "%p -> %l\n"
```

prints all nonbroken symlinks under the directory `.`. I want to colorize this output so that the `%p` part is blue. I've tried

```
find . -type l -not -xtype l -printf '\e[1;34m%-6s\e[m' "%p -> %l\n"
```

but this results in the error `find: warning: unrecognized escape \e`. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not quite correct, the color code sequence and the `%p` needs to be in the same argument to `-printf` and *not* in separate ones.

The `-printf` flag of `find` is different from the usual built-in from `bash`. The `find` version takes arguments of form `-printf format` while the built-in takes `printf <FORMAT> <ARGUMENTS...>`, which means the former doesn't accept format-specifiers followed by arguments but just a single string with options defined. The `-printf` option of `find` provides various sequences to describe the file attributes. The `%s` inside the `find -printf` conveys a different meaning than the format specification definition by the built-in.

Also I guess the `printf` from the `find` (GNU findutils) command only supports ANSI color codes and does not accept the `\e` escape sequences (unlike the built-in `printf` of the GNU shell, on the standalone GNU `printf` utility) but its octal equivalent only (here 033 assuming an ASCII-based system):

```
find . -type l -not -xtype l -printf '\033[1;34m%p\033[m -> %l\n'
```

You can add the ANSI color code of your choice to the above.

Or you can use the `$'...'` quoting operator found in a few shells including the GNU shell, which does recognise `\e`:

```
find . -type l -not -xtype l -printf $'\e[1;34m%p\e[m -> %l\n'
```

Above the `\e` and `\n` are expanded to the ESC and NL characters before being passed to `find`.